# Tinymce textarea not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, tinymce, textarea

My code works fine when I use textbox and not the TinyMce text area. After using TinyMce in my code, data entered in text area is no longer going into my model.

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            width: 900,
            height: 200,
            toolbar1: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline superscript     subscript | cut copy paste ",
            statusbar: false,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: "spellchecker",
            font_formats: "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;" +
       "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" +
       "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;" +
       "Courier New=courier new,courier;" +
       "Georgia=georgia,palatino;" +
       "Helvetica=helvetica;" +
       "Symbol=symbol;" +
       "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" +
       "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;" +
       "Verdana=verdana,geneva;",
            fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt"
        });

    </script>
```

my html File is:

```
<textarea id="QuestionText" ng-model="send.questiontext"></textarea>
{{send}}
```

why is object not getting printed or why is data no longer binded to my model. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are expecting of angular right now is the equivalent of writing some jquery to manipulate the DOM alongside angular. This method is against angular way of doing things.

I suggest you start using the [angular implementation of tinyMCE](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)

And also spend some time reading this [fantastic post about thinking in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: That's not an _angular implementation of tinyMCE_, but a simple binding TO tinyMCE.js.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE keeps its own buffer accessible through `tinymce.activeeditor.[get|set]content()`.

A directive for a quick binding with a ng-model can be found here  :  [codepen : angular directive for tinyMCE](http://codepen.io/paulbhartzog/pen/Ekztl/) , the same code than [angular-ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce).
Fast typers will find it microseconds too slow sometimes.

Other solutions exist to integrate a rich text editor in an angular application :

- [scribe + angular exemple](http://guardian.github.io/scribe-angular-example/) (the demo shows trouble with copy/paste and paragraphs)
- [quill with angular](https://discuss.quilljs.com/t/quill-with-angular-discussion-inside/63) (coffe script exemple)